# Why DOM element is found locally w/without browser but not found when ran in CI?

Tags: javascript, gitlab-ci, cypress

I'm using Cypress for automated testing.

I'm dealing with this piece of code on which tests pass locally with and without
browser but fail within GitLab CI.

html:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const NavBar = props => (

        <nav className="navbar is-dark" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
          <div className="navbar-brand">
            <strong className="navbar-item">
              { props.title }</strong>
              <span className="nav-toggle navbar-burger" onClick={() => {
                  let toggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
                  let menu = document.querySelector('.navbar-menu');
                  toggle.classList.toggle('is-active');
                  menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
                }}>
              <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
            <div className="navbar-menu">
              <div className="navbar-start">
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-item">Home</Link>
                {props.isAuthenticated && <Link to="/about" className="navbar-item">About</Link>}
                {props.isAuthenticated && <Link to="/status" className="navbar-item">User Status</Link>}
              </div>

            <div className="navbar-end">
              {!props.isAuthenticated && <Link to="/register" className="navbar-item" onClick={props.onClearForm}>Register</Link>}
              {!props.isAuthenticated && <Link to="/login" className="navbar-item" onClick={props.onClearForm}>Login</Link>}
              {props.isAuthenticated && <Link to="/logout" className="navbar-item">Logout</Link>}
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    )


export default NavBar;
```

spec file:

```
const string = require('randomstring');
const username = string.generate();
const email = `${username}@mail.com`;

describe('Login', () => {
  it('should display the login form', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    .get('h1').contains('Login')
    .get('form');
  });
  it('should allow user to register', () => {
    cy.visit('/register')
    .get('input[name="username"]').type(username)
    .get('input[name="email"]').type(email)
    .get('input[name="password"]').type('hakunamatata')
    .get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    cy.get('.navbar-burger').click();
    cy.get('.navbar-end').within(() => {
      cy
      .get('.navbar-item').contains('Logout').click();

    });
  });
  it('should allow user to login', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    .get('input[name="email"]').type(email)
    .get('input[name="password"]').type('hakunamatata')
    .get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    cy.wait(100)
    cy.contains('All Users');
    cy.get('.navbar-burger').click();
    cy.get('.navbar-end').within(() => {
      cy
      .get('.navbar-item').contains('Logout').click();

    });
  });

})
```

error output from CI runner:

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'Logout' within the element: [ <a.navbar-item>, 1 more... ] but never did.
      at Context.eval (http://nginx/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/login.spec.js:37398:30)
```

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Cypress version 6.0.0

(this text here is to bypass SO's trigger for not enough details provided)

Comment: It might happen because of speed cypress runs on CI environments, so the component  might not be rendered or the event be not attached during the assertion. In order to confirm it, you could use some static `wait`'s, or create additional assertions by `should` for `.navbar-end` identifier: `cy.get('.navbar-burger').click(); cy.wait(2000);`

Comment: @AlexIzbas  I've added 1000 to the wait and let's see what the outcome will be.

Comment: @AlexIzbas it worked ! Cypress just needed little bit more time on those assertions. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll tick it for you. Thank you !

Comment: Glad it worked @wood. I have just copy-pasted the comment in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might happen because of speed cypress runs on CI environments, so the component might not be rendered or the event be not attached during the assertion.

In order to confirm it, you could use some static `wait`'s, or create additional assertions by `should` for `.navbar-end` identifier:

```
cy.get('.navbar-burger').click(); 
cy.wait(2000);
...
```

*P.S. don't abuse on `wait` commands, as it's an antipattern. There are always better ways to express this in Cypress ;)*

Answer (score 1):

`cy.wait()` is not needed here.

The problem is with the way `contains()` is used.

```
cy.get('.navbar-item').contains('Logout')
```

does not wait for the text 'Logout'.

You should use the format

```
cy.contains('.navbar-item', 'Logout')
```

which will retry everything from reading all the `navbar-items` to checking their text for 'Logout'.